# Many regular expressions into finite state machine

Tags: c++, regex, finite-automata, state-machine

I have a piece of code that calls:

```
regex_search
```

Many times.  Each times it uses a different compiled regular expression (regex object).

This is a performance bottleneck in the code.

I know regular expressions can be converted into a finite state machine.  Multiple regular expressions can be converted into one giant finite state machine with different exit points.  This typically improves speed.

Is there a tool that does this?  Where I can enter ECMA regex (as in C++) and output a finite state machine in C++ or C?

Comment: Wouldn't you achieve the same result by compiling a regex of the form `(regex1)|(regex2)|...` ?

Comment: Please, show examples of your regular expressions (ideally, the most complex ones). And describe, what for do you use it. There are no universal automated converter to regexp, except the regexp parsing and search engine itself, that is usually also represented by a state machine, but in simple cases you could create it by yourself without any problems

Comment: There are faster regex engines out there like `PCRE` you could try.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, that is possible for some groups, but not all, but that is still kinda slow.

Comment: @Galic,  ya probably that may be what I have to do: http://softwareramblings.com/2008/08/c-regular-expression-performance.html.  Thanks for bringing that up.  The results are pretty clear based on that page.

Comment: If you know the regexs at compile time how about a usual parser generator like flex? If not there are libraries such as lexertl (the basis for boost::spirit::lex, although I believe lexertl has moved on quite a bit from what boost uses).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, lexertl  looks great and is exactly what I want.  Give it a bunch of regex, then it builds into a state machine with different exit points.  I didn't see a perf test though.  Probably something I should do.  By the way, these are all great suggestions.  Everyone should write them down as answers, so it's easier for other people to find.